Wordpress Ajax switch style from a button
I want to add a switch button to a banner , so It can change the style between 2 styles.I need to use Ajax. These styles are already settled from another php file ( a form)
/**
 * WoosterBanner class
 * It creates  a banner for the Wooster plugin
 *
 * @package Wooster
 */
class WoosterBanner
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], ['wooster','wooster-followup','wooster-licences','wooster-compagnon','wooster-customers','wooster-partner','wooster-settings','wooster-setup']) && is_admin()) {
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_styles'));
        add_action('in_admin_header', array($this, 'wooster_header_section'));
        add_action('admin_footer', array($this, 'add_switch_style_button'));
        }
    }
    /**
     * Adds the banner to the top of the Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function wooster_header_section()
    {
        ?>
        <div id="top-bar-banner">
            <div class="wooster-banner">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/logo.avif', __DIR__); ?>" alt="Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                <a class="button"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
                <a class="button" id="switch-style"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></a>
                <a class="button"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
        /**
     * Registers the setting for the Wooster plugin style switch button
     *
     * @return void
     */

     public function add_switch_style_button()
     {
     ?>
         <script>
             document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                 var toggleStyleBtn = document.getElementById('switch-style');
                 var currentStyle = localStorage.getItem('wooster_style') || '<?php echo get_option('wooster_style', 'compagnon-wp.css'); ?>';
                 toggleStyleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                     currentStyle = currentStyle === 'compagnon-wp.css' ? 'compagnon-wooster.css' : 'compagnon-wp.css';
                     changeStyle(currentStyle);
                 });

                 function changeStyle(styleName) {
                     var styleElement = document.getElementById('wooster-custom-style');
                     if (!styleElement) {
                         styleElement = document.createElement('link');
                         styleElement.id = 'wooster-custom-style';
                         styleElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
                         document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
                     }
                     styleElement.href = '<?php echo plugins_url('wooster-partner/assets/css/'); ?>' + styleName;
                     localStorage.setItem('wooster_style', styleName);
                 }

                 // Load initial style
                 changeStyle(currentStyle);
             });
         </script>
 <?php
     }


    /**
     * Enqueues the selected style for Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function enqueue_styles()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style('wooster-banner', plugins_url('assets/css/banner.css', __DIR__));
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css', array(), '5.15.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Js library
        wp_localize_script('switch-style', 'switch_style_vars', array(
            'wooster_style_url' => plugins_url("wooster-partner/assets/css/compagnon-wooster.css"),
            'wp_style_url' => plugins_url("wooster-partner/assets/css/compagnon-wp.css"),
        ));
    }
}

new WoosterBanner();

When I click on the switch button it works but only when I settled the wordpress button in setting , when Wooster button was selected, I can't change the style of the css from the button anymore. This is the form for setting :
<?php
/**
 * Class used to manage the display of the content of the settings
 */
class WoosterPartnerSettings
{
    /**
     * Hook to display the contents of the 'Settings' menu if the license is valid
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (get_option('partner_license') && get_option('partner_license') != '') {
            add_action('tab_content_settings', array($this, 'wooster_partner_settings'));
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'display_style'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_style'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows you to display the form to choose the style sheet to display
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function wooster_partner_settings()
    {
?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1><?php echo __('Réglages Wooster', 'wooster-partner'); ?></h1>
            <hr class="line">

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields('wooster-settings-group'); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections('wooster-settings-group'); ?>

                <p class="parag"><?php echo __('Le plugin Compagnon propose deux styles d’affichage :', 'wooster-partner'); ?></p>

                <label for="style_wordpress">
                    <input type="radio" id="style_wordpress" name="wooster_style" value="compagnon-wp.css" <?php checked(get_option('wooster_style'), 'compagnon-wp.css'); ?>>
                    <?php echo __('Style WordPress', 'wooster-partner'); ?>
                </label>

                <label for="style_wooster">
                    <input type="radio" id="style_wooster" name="wooster_style" value="compagnon-wooster.css" <?php checked(get_option('wooster_style'), 'compagnon-wooster.css'); ?>>
                    <?php echo __('Style Wooster', 'wooster-partner'); ?>
                </label><br>

                <input type="submit" class="wooster-button" value="<?php echo __('Enregistrer les modifications', 'wooster-partner') ?>">
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
    }


    /**
     * Registers the setting for the Wooster plugin style
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function display_style()
    {
        register_setting('wooster-settings-group', 'wooster_style');
    }

    /**
     * Enqueues the selected style for Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function enqueue_style()
    {
        if (is_admin()) {
            if (isset($_GET['page']) && strpos($_GET['page'], 'wooster') === 0) {
                $selected_style = get_option('wooster_style', 'compagnon-wp.css'); // default style
                wp_enqueue_style('wooster-custom-style', plugins_url('wooster-partner/assets/css/' . $selected_style));
            }
        }
    }
    }
new WoosterPartnerSettings();



Why are you registering wp_ajax_switch_load and wp_ajax_nopriv_show_wooster_settings_callback as callbacks, why do these names not "match"? And why are you even registering a wp_ajax_nopriv_ callback here to begin with - are users who are not even logged in, supposed to be able to use this functionality?

yes indeed, I updated it and removed method I didn't used. It seems to work but only when Wordpress setting is set
